# Remove or disable a built-in voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

I am wondering whether there is any way to remove or disable a built-in voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking ( e.g., `shut down Windows`).

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

> **Remove or disable a built-in voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?**
>
> I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64
>   Ultimate

[**Dragon Naturally Speaking version 12 - Installation and User Guide**](http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/dragon/@web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_025216.pdf)

> ### **Changes that make Dragon faster and more accurate**
>
> **Disable unused voice commands:**
>
> **Turn off what you're not using and Dragon runs faster**
>
> If you don't use commands to open programs and folders, or to control
>   menus, buttons, and other controls in your programs, now Dragon has
>   options to turn them off. With Dragon no longer listening for those
>   types of commands, the speed of dictation recognition increases.
>
> - To turn off control of Start menu and Desktop items, on the DragonBar go to Tools > Options > Commands, and turn off and Enable
>     launching from the Desktop.
> - To turn off control of menus, buttons, or other controls in one or more programs, on the DragonBar go to Tools > Options > Miscellaneous
>     Voice-enable menus, buttons, and other controls. You can turn off control of all programs or selected programs on the list, which
>     includes Microsoft Outlook, Lotus Notes, Internet Explorer, Microsoft
>     Word and WordPad, Microsoft Excel, WordPerfect, Notepad, and Dragon
>     NaturallySpeaking for Windows
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**PAGE 19**</sub>

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't allow to disable the `shut down Windows` voice command.